# How to analyse disk usage in command line linux?

Tags: linux, disk-space, du, df

`du` and `df` are nice, but I don't know how to filter the data they provide the way I do with [SequoiaView](https://web.archive.org/web/20151109063233/http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview/). I would like to know which are the largest folders and the largest files in a glance.

Comment: Have you trued `ncdu`?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Tracking down where disk space has gone on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125429)

Answer (score 208, accepted):

You might also want to try the [NCurses Disk Usage](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) aka `ncdu`.

Use it like `ncdu -x -q` if you're invoking it remotely (e. g. via `ssh`) and `ncdu -x` otherwise.

```
ncdu 1.6 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help
    --- /home/geek -----------------------------------------------------------------
       27.6MiB  /qm test 1 rework
      312.0kiB  /sidebar
       88.0kiB  /rackerhacker-MySQLTuner-perl-6add618
        8.0kiB  /.w3m
        4.0kiB  /.cache
    e   4.0kiB  /.ssh
      160.0kiB   ng.tar.gz
       76.0kiB   plowshare_1~svn1673-1_all.deb
        4.0kiB   .bashrc
        4.0kiB   .bash_history
        4.0kiB   .profile
        4.0kiB   .htoprc
        4.0kiB   .bash_logout
        0.0  B   .lesshst
```

This is available under Mac OS X too.

The following flags to the command line might be helpful:

```
-q Quiet mode, doesn't update the screen 10 times a second
   while scanning, reduces network bandwidth used

-x Don't cross filesystem borders (don't descend into a
   directory which is a mounted disk)
```

Thanks to Sorin Sbarnea.

Comment: Available under OS X too, via brew. It may be a good idea to call it using `ncdu -x -q`

Comment: awesome! the best option for me was `ncdu -q`, even in ssh.

Comment: The best one! Thank you.

Answer (score 55):

Use some combination of the commands and options:

```
du --max-depth=1 2> /dev/null | sort -n -r | head -n20
```

to view only the largest few. If you'd like to use it a lot, then bind it to an alias, e.g. in bash by adding to ~/.bashrc

```
alias largest='du --max-depth=1 2> /dev/null | sort -n -r | head -n20'
```

Comment: To view the **largest** few, you need the `-r` option on sort.

Comment: I submitted @RedGrittyBrick suggestion and an error redirection to `/dev/null` as an edit subject to approval.

Comment: I would also use the `du -H` option, but it breaks the `sort` behavior

Comment: What does `2>` do?

Comment: @jumpnett: it redirects `standard error` (in this case into the black hole that is `/dev/null`).

Comment: You can use ``sort -h`` to sort values with human readable suffixes.

Comment: My modified version of this to display values in human readable format: `du -h --max-depth=1 2> /dev/null | sort -h -r`

Comment: And for OSX `du -d 1 -xh 2> /dev/null | sort -h -r | head -n20`

Comment: This works, but I don’t think it’s a good fit for this question. On machines with a large number of files you’ll likely want something that scans the disk only once and then allow you to browse the result (like `ncdu`).

Answer (score 11):

I would like to recommend [dutree](https://github.com/nachoparker/dutree), which offers a hierachical visualization.

You can select more or less levels of detail, and exclude paths for better control of visualization. You can also compare different paths.

[image]

It is implemented in Rust, fast and efficient.

```
$ dutree -h
Usage: dutree [options] <path> [<path>..]

Options:
    -d, --depth [DEPTH] show directories up to depth N (def 1)
    -a, --aggr [N[KMG]] aggregate smaller than N B/KiB/MiB/GiB (def 1M)
    -s, --summary       equivalent to -da, or -d1 -a1M
    -u, --usage         report real disk usage instead of file size
    -b, --bytes         print sizes in bytes
    -f, --files-only    skip directories for a fast local overview
    -x, --exclude NAME  exclude matching files or directories
    -H, --no-hidden     exclude hidden files
    -A, --ascii         ASCII characters only, no colors
    -h, --help          show help
    -v, --version       print version number
```

Comment: when will appear in brew? nix?

Comment: @DaneelYaitskov Yesterday; cargo install dutree

Comment: The website linked above is gone now, but the source code still exists: https://github.com/nachoparker/dutree Hasn't been updated in 5 years tho.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want `xdu`.

```
du -ax | xdu -n
```

There's also the more sophisticated KDE-based [Filelight](http://methylblue.com/filelight/).

Answer (score 3):

I usually use

```
du -hsc * | sort -h
```

What each option means for `du`:

- h: show sizes in human readable format (1K, 1M, 1G, ...)
- s: summarize: display only a total for each argument
- c: also display a grand total

The `-h` option on `sort` makes it understand the `-h` format (human readable) on `du`. This option is relatively new on `sort`, so maybe your system does not support it and forces you to use `du -sc | sort -n` instead.

If you do it on a remote machine and the process takes a long time, you probably want to execute this process backgrounded or inside a `screen` or something similar to prevent a connection loss.

Answer (score 2):

```
du -h 2> /dev/null | sort -hr | head -n20
```

**du -h** gives a human readable list estimate of disk space with a total
**2> /dev/null** suppresses any errors such as read access denied
**sort -hr** sorts the human readable file size in reverse order
**head -n20** reduce the list to 20

Be aware that read access denied directories and files are excluded

Answer (score 0):

To know which are the largest folders and the largest files in a glance, you can also use the command line tool 'Top Disk Usage' (`tdu`):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425615/how-to-get-top-immediate-sub-folders-of-folder-consuming-huge-disk-space-in/501089#501089